# Looping a scraper

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data for all the games of a team in a regular season scraped from http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201112250DAL.html. I got all other data farming functions working fine, the problem I have is with looping the scraper. 
This is the test code I used to get the URL of the next page. I could use this, to get the data from all 66 games that a team played during regular season, but that's a lot of typing to scrape it this way. What would be the simplest solution to automate this?

Thank you!

```
URL = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201112250DAL.html" 

html = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

def getLink(html, soup):
    links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'bold_text'})
    if len(links) == 2:
        a = links[0]
        a = str(a)
        a = a[37:51]
        return a
    if len(links) == 3:
        a = links[1]
        a = str(a)
        a = a[37:51]
        return a
    if len(links) == 4:
        a = links[3]
        a = str(a)
        a = a[37:51]
        return a

print getLink(html, soup)
URL1 = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores" + getLink(html, soup) + "html"
print URL1
html1 = urlopen(URL1).read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)

print getLink(html1, soup1)
```

Comment: if you're just trying to work out the URLs, would it be easier to instead just grab http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/DAL/2012_games.html and literally, strip out strings that look like "/boxscores/*.html" ? That'll get you the 66 regular games plus the playoffs..

Comment: This is just a test, to go trough URLs, there's functions in the main code, that take stats im interested in from every game. I was just wondering how to make this process as fast as possible.

Comment: I was thinking sort of using the /DAL/2012_games.html page as your index? You can retrieve that once, and easily get the 66 URLs you need and stick that in a list then feed that in. Sort of bypassing the entire scraping of the page for the correct 'next game' link (since I didn't see any simple patterns to match against)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to go to http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/DAL/2012_games.html and do something like this:

```
URL = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/DAL/2012_games.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

links = soup.findAll('a',text='Box Score')
```

This returns a list of all `<a>` tags with text of 'Box Score'. Test it with this:

```
for link in links:
    print link.parent['href']
    page_url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com' + link.parent['href']
```

From here, make another request to `page_url` and continue coding.

This is the entire code I used, and it worked perfectly for me:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib


url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/DAL/2012_games.html'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

links = soup.findAll('a',text='Box Score')
for link in links:
    print link.parent['href']
```

Comment: Thnx, I never thought of trying it this way. Gave your idea a quick test and it didnt work; I got a KeyError: 'href'.

Comment: Are you sure you want the parent's href? In this case, you're going to get a KeyError since the parent of the A tag is going to be a TD, which is going to throw the KeyError. It works fine if you instead access the link's href attribute (`link['href']` instead of `link.parent['href']`)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest easiest way would be to use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).  Which follow links for you automatically.

It allows you to easily create complex rules on which urls to follow and ignore.  Scrapy will then follow any url that matches your rules.  It does require you to learn how scrapy works, but they provide an excellent quick tutorial on how to get started.